# Is delegating a granular "Modify permission" on a group possible?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, permissions, access-control-list, groups

A certain user "x" has below permissions on a group "g";

-> Read/Write all the properties on group.
-> Delete the group.

Need to add "modify permissions" on the group "g" for user "x" ; but the only ACL x is used to add is "SELF" for any object.

Is above scenario possible?

Please let me know if any more info needed.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to grant permission to add only a specific ACE.